# Adding Esri imagery to QGIS using "services.argisonline.com"

Tags: qgis, arcgis-online, imagery

I'm trying to add this particular imagery in QGIS:

http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/3

But when i write the phyton srcipt i get the message that the URL is incorrect.

I'm getting this typical message:
"Cannot open GDAL dataset [http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/serââvices/World_Imagery/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true](http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/ser%C3%A2%C3%A2vices/World_Imagery/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true):
Failed to create temporary file:/tmp/file.dat"

Anyone know what is the correct URL for High Resolution 30cm Imagery?

Comment: http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true without the two accented a's in the middle seems to work

Comment: ooops...I didn't write any â! And when i took them out i get this message: Cannot open GDAL dataset http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true:
Invalid dataset dimensions : -2147483648 x -2147483648

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169012/esri-world-imagery-raster-layer-not-working-in-python-console/169013?noredirect=1#comment252099_169013).  This reported a different error but involves a bug with adding Esri imagery to QGIS.

Comment: Can you post the python code snippet that you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I use the [QuickMapServices](https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices) or the [TileLayerPlugin](https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin) plugins (see [OpenStreetMap heavily pixellated when loaded in QGIS and standalone application](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/166534/2581)). They automatically set the scale to the fixed resolutions of the zoom levels.

For the TileLayerPlugin, the URI is

```
#title  credit  serviceUrl  yOriginTop  zmin    zmax    xmin    ymin    xmax    ymax
ArcgisWorldImagery  esri    http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.png    1   0   16  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
```

For the QuickMapServices, the URI is is referenced  in the [Quickmapservices contribution](https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices_contrib) site ([ArcGIS online imagery](https://github.com/nextgis/quickmapservices_contrib/tree/master/data_sources/arcgis_online_imagery))

[image]