# I don't really understand how .xml files interact with QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I just saw [Why are the Google basemaps no longer appearing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172019/why-are-the-google-basemaps-no-longer-appearing-in-qgis) and I don't understand the answer from user Thomas Horner.

Could someone explain why a .xml can be loaded as a raster?

Comment: That XML file gives the necessary configuration info for GDAL so that it knows what to do. See http://www.gdal.org/frmt_wms.html.

Answer (score 2):

Open Notepad

Copy and paste the XML from the thread you're mentioning above

Save the Notepad file as Google.xml

in QGIS > Layer > Add Layer > Add Raster Layer

Browse to the Google.xml

You should see the Google Satellite Image in your map

Comment: You can even drag and drop the .xml onto the canvas or layers panel.