# How to download images from google maps using RgoogleMaps

Tags: r, google-maps

I'm trying to download images from Google Maps using the package "RgoogleMaps" in R (getmap function). But I need to download a lot of images, so I've been thinking to create a fishnet in QGIS and import the coordinates to R, but I don't know how to import it to create a loop and download the images.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you just looking to have the images displayed as a layer in QGIS?

Comment: yes, then i'll try to stitch them to cover an area of interest to do an unsupervised classification or feature extraction. I'm trying to identify the rooftop of buildings, and i've been thinking that google's image could be useful.

Comment: Please, add some code to show some effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to see google images as a layer in QGIS you could bring them into QGIS as a raster (.xml file) as suggested in this answer.

[Why are the Google basemaps no longer appearing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172019/why-are-the-google-basemaps-no-longer-appearing-in-qgis)