# Google Streets XML as raster layer

Tags: raster, openlayers, xml, google, streets

I found [Why are the Google basemaps no longer appearing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172019) which explains a simple method to reach the google tile server and get the Google Physical tiles. Has anyone a similar code with which I can get the Google Streets tiles? I'm unfortunately not really into programming and just a user of QGIS which is why I have to ask this question.

I'm using QGIS 2.14.8 and I'm unfortunately not able to upgrade right now. So using XYZ tiles or QuickMapServices is not possible. I am using OpenLayers plugin but this one is way too often not working the way I'd like it to work.

Comment: You want the tiles in QGIS? XYZ tiles is the answer > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272778/will-the-openlayers-plugin-be-updated-for-qgis3/272802

Comment: I forgot to say that I am unfortunately using QGIS 2.14.8, and I'm not able to upgrade at the moment. Otherwise I would use XYZ tiles or QuickMapServices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TileLayerPlugin. More info on https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin

It is a available in the QGIS plugin repository, so you should be able to install it from within QGIS.